# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, laravel, phpmyadmin, laravel-5.4

I am fairly new to Laravel framework. I keep getting this error when trying to register a user. I am able to do table migration so I know the connection works.Below is the info I have in my .env file. I am able to successfully migrate too, check below.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=classified
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=null
```

current config of database.php file

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'classified'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', null),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

The database also holds the migrated SQL files. So the connection works, however actually trying to register or login throws that error.

```
1/2
PDOException in Connector.php line 68:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

2/2
QueryException in Connection.php line 647:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `email` = user@gmail.com)
```

I am using **MySQL** and **not** using **Homestead**.I do not know where exactly it's getting the information from that it's trying to use, but if its not from the .env. This is a new install made minutes ago. All I did was enter the MySQL data in, perform auth, migrate to register. I am using Laravel 5.4

Comment: Try to clear your config first `php artisan config:clear`. See if it works.

Comment: It worked. Had to close all terminals and restart service. Thank you

Comment: Well there should be a proper answer. Posting that

Answer (score 3):

use these commands:

```
php artisan config:clear

php artisan cache:clear

php artisan config:cache
```

Then run again

Answer (score 1):

Try to clear your config first `php artisan config:clear`. See if it works.

Restart Laraver Server